# Generate PDF in Android without any 3rd party Library

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdf-generation

I need to generate PDF from my application using `PdfDocument` class introduced in API 19. I don't want to use any 3rd party library.
Here is what I have done

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 300, 1).create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
View content = findViewById(R.id.testText);
content.draw(page.getCanvas());
document.finishPage(page);
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/AppName";
File dir = new File(fullPath);
File file = new File(fullPath, "TripReport.PDF");
if (!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdirs();
if (file.exists())
    file.delete();
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
document.writeTo(os);
document.close();
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong?` - only if you tell us what's going wrong.

Comment: You want to create a proprietary binary file and you don't want any sort of library to help you with that.  Ok.  Good luck.

Comment: @durbnpoisn He didn't say that.  He said no 3rd party library.  `PdfDocument` is designed exactly for that.

Comment: Ah.  I kinda took that to mean that he didn't even like the Class that's built in...  (isn't that a library, after all?)

Comment: @durbnpoisn but it isn't 3rd party - is it...?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time. I don't need the solution now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have simple solution and it also worked.........

```
try{                
    File docfile=new File(""+getExternalFilesDir("parent dir"),"filename.pdf");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(docfile), "application/pdf");                
    startActivity(intent);
}
catch (Exception e) {}
```